# What conditions activate the Great Weapon Master feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

Part of the [Great Weapon Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/great-weapon-master) feat (PHB, p. 167) says:

> On your turn, when you score a critical hit with a melee weapon or
>   reduce a creature to 0 hit points with **one**, you can make one melee
>   weapon attack as a bonus action.

I quiet don't understand what is meant by ***one***, the ***critical hit*** or the ***melee weapon***?
First I thought, if I kill a creature with one hit, I get a bonus action. Then a friend told me, ***one*** means the ***critical hit*** and the information

> ...or reduce a creature to 0 hit points with **one**...

is redundant, since no matter if the creature dies or not, as long as it's a critical hit (but only then) I get a bonus action.
Also, if my first assumption is true, and a one hit kill as well as a critical hit gets me a bonus action, can I get another bonus action from this, if the prerequisites are met, and so on.

*The idea by choosing GWM, besides all the other great opportunities this feat grants, was the chance of killing a whole group of weak enemies with my raging barbarian.*

Comment: Related on [What does upper case A Attack action vs lower case a attack action mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781/what-does-upper-case-a-attack-action-vs-lower-case-a-attack-mean) and [Does the extra attack from great weapon master apply to all melee weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130397/does-the-extra-attack-from-great-weapon-master-apply-to-all-melee-weapons)

Comment: You're right. It is a pity the feat does not stack with the Berserker-Barbarian's bonus attack. So to say, a raging Berserker presumably already is the one true GWM and what you would want to do is only possible with the Ranger's Volley action.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## "One" is referencing the melee attack

What GWM does is give you the option to perform a single additional melee attack as a *bonus action* if you either roll a critical hit or reduce a target's HP to zero (either by killing them or simply getting them to 0 HP) while using a melee weapon.

### There can be only one

It is important to note that you only ever get one single bonus action per turn. Therefore, you cannot kill a group of weak enemies since you are still limited by the standard action economy of having available, in a given turn, your **Attack** action and your **bonus action.**

Comment: Thank you NautArch, this answer is at least between what I feared and what I hoped. So now as you refering to the "standard action economy", how about my bonus action when being in Frenzy Rage? Do I'm loosing this bonus action when critting or one-hitting as GWM?

Comment: @RaymondOsterbrink You only get one Bonus Action per turn. So you'd need to choose whether or not to Frenzy for it or to use your GWM. I also suggest waiting a bit for other answers to come in just to make sure someone doesn't haven answer you think is written better or has better info. And welcome to the site!

Answer (score 4):

A pronoun always refers to the closest noun in the sentence/phrase or previous sentence that serves the same grammatical function. In this case, the corresponding phrases are "with a melee weapon" and "with one". Thus, One refers to "melee weapon".

So you get a bonus attack, if you get a critical hit or if you kill (reduce to 0 HP) a creature when making an attack with a melee weapon.

Note: you can only have one bonus action per turn. So if you have already used it, you will not have the option to make a second attack. Or if you make a second attack, you will not be able to use a bonus action from a different feat/ability.

A Diagram of the quoted sentence:
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that English pronoun usage doesn't fall into the simple pattern you describe. For example: "Kathy's the best in the squad; she's stronger than Sarah, she's faster than Allie, and she's a better shot than Jenny" ('Sarah' is the closest noun to the second use of 'she', but it refers to 'Kathy'). Or: "What's that in the street?" "It's huge!" ('It' refers to the pronoun 'that', not 'the street').

Comment: in your sentence, She is the subject of the phrases, the only noun used as a subject is Kathy. same for the second example; "It" and "that" are the subjects " the street" is the object of a preposition. you need to apply the entire condition not just half of it.

Comment: @Marq nearest refers to gramatical definition of the distance;  not by a literal word position. Since it's English, it's a train wreck to explain.  E.g. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56376/what-does-them-refer-to-here but also to illustrate the ambiguity https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7125/how-are-pronouns-resolved

Comment: “a melee weapon” is the object of the preposition “with”

Comment: @James - and so is "one", which is why "one" refers to "a melee weapon".

Comment: Yeah but there’s the conjunction ‘or’ separating the two sentence fragments.  Would you like burger with fries or fish with them?  ‘Them’ is at best unclear.

Comment: @James - I'm not sure what your point is. You seem to be trying to disprove my rule by giving examples that prove it. In your sentence, "with fries" corresponds to "with them", additionally "fries" is the only plural noun; thus, "them" must refer to "fries". If you intended "them" to refer to "burger with fries" then the sentence is ungrammatical because the two phrases joined by "or" don't have parallel agreement.

Answer (score 4):

### **"One" in this case refers to a melee weapon**

Specifically, the Great Weapon Master feat allows you to use a bonus action to make a melee attack if *either* of the following conditions are true:

- You make a critical hit with a melee weapon
- You reduce an enemy to 0 hit points with a melee weapon

Two things to note here (based on what you wrote and a potential misunderstanding you may have):

You **only** need to reduce the enemy to 0 hit points with a melee attack.  You do **not** need to do so in only a single hit.  In other words, if you hit an enemy three times over three turns, and then on the fourth turn hit them and reduce their hp to 0, you can use your bonus action to make a melee attack on that turn.

You **only** get *one* bonus action per turn.  If you have something else you can do with a bonus action (such as a spell or other class feature) you have to pick which you want to do.  You can't use the bonus action attack from Great Weapon Master and Frenzy in the same turn, for example.  You have to pick which you wish to use (perhaps a bad example given they both do the same thing: allow you to make an attack; but point is you can't make *two* bonus action attacks, only one).

*Note:*  DnD has many instances of language use like this.  If English is not your first language, or you just generally have questions about some of the language use, there is also an [English Language stack exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com) (and an [English Language Learners stack exchange](https://elu.stackexchange.com)) that would be willing to help teach some of these usages.